# How to navigate from one screen to another using on click function for desktop application using flex(flash builder 4.6)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop application in flex wherein i have 2 screen(i.e is mxml windowedapplication) .i want to navigate from one one screen to another(from mxml file to another) .how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ViewNavigator in your desktop applications, just need to do some tricks

1. add to your project StageOrientationEvent class

   package flash.events
   {

   ```
   public class StageOrientationEvent extends Event
   {
       static public const ORIENTATION_CHANGE:String = "orientationChange";
       static public const ORIENTATION_CHANGING:String = "orientationChanging";

       public function StageOrientationEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
       {
           super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. create new skin for ViewNavigator

   < s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
       xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" alpha.disabled="0.5" >

   ```
   <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("spark.components.ViewNavigator")]</fx:Metadata>

   <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
       <![CDATA[         

           override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number) : void
           {
               super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
           }
       ]]>        
   </fx:Script>

   <s:states>
       <s:State name="normal" />
       <s:State name="disabled" />
       <s:State name="landscape" />
       <s:State name="portrait" />
       <s:State name="landscapeAndOverlay" />
       <s:State name="portraitAndOverlay" />
   </s:states>

   <s:Group id="contentGroup" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
       <s:layout>
           <s:BasicLayout/>
       </s:layout>
   </s:Group>
   ```

   < /s:Skin>
3. Add mobilecomponents.swc to your project (you can find it in flex sdk folder, in my case path is C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs\mobile\mobilecomponents.swc)
4. assign your new ViewNavigator skin (step 2) to ViewNavigator

direct to ViewNavigator instance:

```
<s:ViewNavigator skinClass="path.to.skin.ViewNavigatorSkin"/>
```

or globally in css

```
s|ViewNavigator{
     skinClass: ClassReference("path.to.skin.ViewNavigatorSkin");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways, but I'd probably use one of these:

1. You can use [States](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ff1.html) to change the screen
2. You could use a [ViewStack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e4d.html) or other Navigator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply ..bt it isnt exactly required...i want navigation from one screen to another screen(from one mxml file to another mxmlfile).as we use for mobile in flex(navigator.push view())..like this

Comment: @francisdcunha When converting a mobile application to the web; I switched from the Mobile Navigator to States.